# How to develop coloring pages application for iPhone/ iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an application in which I have to develop coloring pages for kids. I have no idea about how to do it. So, I need start up hints. In which form the page will be presented? Will it be an Image? How to identify part of an image in page to fill with color? What else will help developing it?

Comment: By coloring pages you mean something like a shape drawn with black lines and the kid has to fill out the white/empty closed areas with color?

Comment: Yes. And shape can be any random shape like some character, animal, objects, etc. A page may contain a full scene rather then one or two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a book on iPhone / Objective C development and work through the examples. Starting with basic labels, text fields and table views. Doing your own custom drawing based on user gestures will be easier to learn once you have a handle on the basics.

Comment: I am familiar with the basic. Custom drawing on user gestures is not the requirement. Pages will be the external resource. That is why, I need some guideline on how to interpret them in the app. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at overriding [UIView drawRect], and using the CG methods to create and fill paths/shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using png with transparent areas for the areas which should be filled. Then coloring could be done on a deeper layer, so the borders of the shape aren't painted over. I would directly paint on the "coloring" layer. An eraser could easily be created as a white brush or whatever color the paper should have.

Comment: Thanks Nick for giving the direction. I'll try it out.